# How to attach functions with Annotation Processing

Tags: kotlin, annotations, linear-algebra

I'm thinking of a new technique in a program I'm trying to complete. The program is centred around linear algebra. My current approach to the program is to use classes, but that's boring. I am trying to accomplish it with annotations like below.

```
fun main() {
    @Matrix
    val A = arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(1, 2),
        intArrayOf(-2, 0)
    )

    val B = A.inv() // function provided by annotating LOCAL_VARIABLE

    @Matrix
    val example = arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(-3, 0, 1),
        intArrayOf(4, 9),
        intArrayOf(3, -2, -1)
     ) // -> Error: invalid matrix
}
```

I can understand how to create *constants* using annotation processing and running the generated code file for execution. But how to add extension functions and validate code like the following example.

Answer (score 0):

i am gussing this is what you want you can mark each property with @Matrix annotation and then check and validate each property that has this anotaotion

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

@Target(allowedTargets = [AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY])
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Matrix {
    companion object {
        fun <T> validate(
            caller: T,
            prop: KProperty1<out T, Any?>
        ) {
            if (prop.annotations.any { it is CollectionNotEmpty }) {
                val getter = prop.getter
                getter.isAccessible = true
                val value = getter.call(caller) as? Collection<*>
                    ?: throw  IllegalArgumentException("${prop.name} : is not a collection")
                    // not valid matrix ...
            }
        }
    }
}



class anotationExample() {
    @Matrix
    val A = arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(1, 2),
        intArrayOf(-2, 0)
    )

    @Matrix
    val example = arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(-3, 0, 1),
        intArrayOf(4, 9),
        intArrayOf(3, -2, -1)
     ) 
        companion object {
    
            @JvmStatic
            fun main(args: Array<String>) {
                for (prop in this::class.memberProperties) {
                    CollectionNotEmpty.validate(this, prop)
                }
            }
    
   
    }
```